# Is any chance to create new instanceable class or type from N mixed case classes?

Tags: scala, reflection, metaprogramming

Let's assume I've case classes like below:

```
case class Id(id: Long)
case class Department(number: Long)
case class Employee(name: String, surname: String)
```

Now I would like to merge these classes into new one and make the instance of that type without writing the another class:

```
type UberEmployee = Employee with Department with Id
val uberEmployeeInstance = new UberEmployee("Jon", "Smith", 1200, 1)
```

or

```
val uberEmployeeInstance = MagicFactory[UberEmployee]("Jon", "Smith", 1200, 1)
```

Is any possibility to achieve this in Scala with metaprogramming or reflection? Class composition with mixins doesn't work for me in my imaginary case.

Answer (score 1):

It can't really be done with inheritance since only traits support multiple inheritance, so the best you can do is auto-generated conversion methods. I assume you could do it with reflection or some sort of code generation. But probably the easiest path is to use [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless). In fact, this is an example straight out of the [shapeless guide](https://github.com/underscoreio/shapeless-guide/blob/develop/dist/shapeless-guide.pdf) (page 75):

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.hlist._

trait Migration[A, B] {
  def apply(a: A): B
}

implicit class MigrationOps[A](a: A) {
  def migrateTo[B](implicit migration: Migration[A, B]): B = migration(a)
}

implicit def genericMigration[A, B, ARepr <: HList, BRepr <: HList](
  implicit aGen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, ARepr], bGen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[B, BRepr],
  inter: Intersection.Aux[ARepr, BRepr, BRepr]): Migration[A, B] = new Migration[A, B] {
  def apply(a: A): B = bGen.from(inter(aGen.to(a)))
}
```

Then just define your "uber" class with all the relevant fields and call `.migrateTo`:

```
case class UberEmployee(id: Long, number: Long, name: String, surname: String)

UberEmployee(123, 456, "John", "Doe").migrateTo[Employee]  // returns Employee("John", "Doe")
```